# Using multiple Cross Joins with JSON seems to slow my query right down and never completes

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have the following JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "UserDetails": [
      {
        "UserName": "User1",
        "UserDateOfBirth": "06/11/89",
        "UserID": "12345",
        "NotesDay1": [
          {
            "NoteID": "a287fcc4",
            "AnswerType": 1,
            "RemedialText": null,
            "Details": null,
            "UserLocation": 0,
            "DateDone": "2021-08-06T00:19:14"
          },
          {
            "NoteID": "4a48385a",
            "AnswerType": 1,
            "RemedialText": null,
            "Details": null,
            "UserLocation": 0,
            "DateDone": "2021-08-06T02:19:59"
          },
          {
            "NoteID": "ddb6bc52",
            "AnswerType": 1,
            "RemedialText": null,
            "Details": null,
            "UserLocation": 0,
            "DateDone": "2021-08-06T04:14:50"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "UserName": "User2",
        "UserDateOfBirth": "05/08/99",
        "UserID": "23456",
        "NotesDay1": [],
        "NotesDay2": [
          {
            "NoteID": "62cf5478",
            "AnswerType": 1,
            "RemedialText": null,
            "Details": null,
            "UserLocation": 0,
            "DateDone": "2021-08-07T01:00:48"
          },
          {
            "NoteID": "7f864ef4",
            "AnswerType": 1,
            "RemedialText": null,
            "Details": null,
            "UserLocation": 0,
            "DateDone": "2021-08-07T01:00:48"
          },
          {
            "NoteID": "db1a0af0",
            "AnswerType": 1,
            "RemedialText": null,
            "Details": null,
            "UserLocation": 0,
            "DateDone": "2021-08-07T06:28:02"
          }
         ],
        "NotesDay3": [
          {
            "NoteID": "2ae6b923",
            "AnswerType": 1,
            "RemedialText": null,
            "Details": null,
            "UserLocation": 0,
            "DateDone": "2021-08-07T06:28:02"
          }
        ],
        "NotesDay4": [],
        "NotesDay5": [],
        "NotesDay6": [],
        "NotesDay7": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My current SQL query to import this is set up as below:

```
SELECT j2.UserID, j3.NoteID1, j4.NoteID2, j5.NoteID3, j6.NoteID4, j7.NoteID5, j8.NoteID6, j9.NoteID7
INTO [UserDayNotes]
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON) 
WITH
    (
        UserDetails nvarchar(max) '$.UserDetails' as JSON
    ) j1
    
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.UserDetails) WITH
(
        UserID nvarchar(100) '$.UserID',
        NotesDay1 nvarchar(max) '$.NotesDay1' as JSON,
        NotesDay2 nvarchar(max) '$.NotesDay2' as JSON,
        NotesDay3 nvarchar(max) '$.NotesDay3' as JSON,
        NotesDay4 nvarchar(max) '$.NotesDay4' as JSON,
        NotesDay5 nvarchar(max) '$.NotesDay5' as JSON,
        NotesDay6 nvarchar(max) '$.NotesDay6' as JSON,
        NotesDay7 nvarchar(max) '$.NotesDay7' as JSON
) j2
    
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j2.NotesDay1) WITH
(
        NoteID1 nvarchar(100) '$.NoteID'
) j3
    
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j2.CareNotesDay2) WITH
(
        NoteID2 nvarchar(100) '$.NoteID'
) j4
    
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j2.CareNotesDay3) WITH
(
        NoteID3 nvarchar(100) '$.NoteID'
) j5
    
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j2.CareNotesDay4) WITH
(
        NoteID4 nvarchar(100) '$.NoteID'
) j6

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j2.CareNotesDay5) WITH
(
        NoteID5 nvarchar(100) '$.NoteID'
) j7

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j2.CareNotesDay6) WITH
(
        NoteID6 nvarchar(100) '$.NoteID'
) j8 

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j2.CareNotesDay7) WITH
(
        NoteID3 nvarchar(100) '$.NoteID'
) j9
```

If I run the query as it is, then it runs forever and ever and never completes. If I comment out all but j2.UserID, j3.NoteID1 and j4.NoteID2, then the query runs more or less instantly. I'm assuming this is something to do with the number of cross apply items I have, but my experience and knowledge of this side of SQL is not great, and I could really use some help.

After discussions below, I've realised I could have multiple instances of Day1, Day 2 etc and so a more realistic desired output would be below:

| UserID | DayNumber | NoteID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 1 | a287fcc4 |
| User1 | 1 | 4a48385a |
| User1 | 1 | ddb6bc52 |
| User2 | 2 | 62cf5478 |
| User2 | 2 | 7f864ef4 |
| User2 | 2 | db1a0af0 |
| User2 | 3 | 2ae6b923 |

(Good lord, that table took some doing!)

The data inside each NotesDayX object is a repeat of information held elsewhere, so as long as I have the NoteID then I can dispense with the other info contained within the JSON.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your outer root object is an array, does this always only have one index or multiple? Do each of the `NotesDay` array properties always only contain a single object also?

Comment: On second thoughts, there is something very strange about this JSON: the object located in `$[0].UserDetails[1]` *also* contains a *UserDetails* property, in other words it is nested a second time, whereas the first object is not. Is this JSON a correct example, or are there missing or extra brackets somewhere?

Comment: @Charlieface I've amended the original JSON to include more anonymised structure. I had simplified it more the first time for the purposes of this post, and although it's still a bit edited, the structure is more like as it appears in full.

Comment: Essentially, UserDetails is an array with several objects containing user info. Within those objects is a further set of arrays that track data over 7 days, each called NotesDay 1...NotesDay7. I only really require the NoteID string within each of them. Each NotesDayX may contain several or no objects indicating entries on that day based on different actions performed by the user.

Comment: OK so please answer: the outer array does it always only have one object in it? And given that there are now multiple note objects per `NotesDay` array, how do you want to represent that?

Comment: @Charlieface you gave me a D'oh! moment, as TBH I'd forgotten about there being multiple DayX entries. Remember, this isn't my actual job but doing the best I can to make better use of the data we use. The software I'm extracting the data from shows this information in a grid pattern, with multiple entries for any day in particular shown as links to click to drill down the data. With this in mind, multiple entries of User ID, NotesDay1...7 with perhaps a DateDone field?

Comment: So you want three columns `UserID, NoteID, NotesDay`? Or something else? Perhaps you should modify your expected output above?

Comment: @Charlieface I've done this. Because I can get the other data elsewhere in the system, all I need is the user, the day number out of 7, and the note ID. But yes, there will be multiple instances of eg Day 1, maybe nothing in Day 2 or 3, but then subsequently every day after that until 7. Or, there may just be one Day 5, etc. My original code above did work for the first two NotesDayX, but then gets stuck after that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could union all the `Notes` arrays together.**

Furthermore, it's unclear if the outer array always has only a single inner object, if so then we can use `$[0]` and skip the first `OPENJSON`

```sql
SELECT
    j1.UserID,
    j2.DayNumber,
    j2.NoteID
INTO [UserDayNotes]
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$[0].UserDetails')
  WITH
  (
        UserID nvarchar(100),
        NotesDay1 nvarchar(max) as JSON,
        NotesDay2 nvarchar(max) as JSON,
        NotesDay3 nvarchar(max) as JSON,
        NotesDay4 nvarchar(max) as JSON,
        NotesDay5 nvarchar(max) as JSON,
        NotesDay6 nvarchar(max) as JSON,
        NotesDay7 nvarchar(max) as JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 1 AS DayNumber, NoteID
    FROM OPENJSON(j1.NotesDay1) WITH
    (
        NoteID nvarchar(100)
    ) j2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS DayNumber, NoteID
    FROM OPENJSON(j1.NotesDay2) WITH
    (
        NoteID nvarchar(100)
    ) j2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS DayNumber, NoteID
    FROM OPENJSON(j1.NotesDay3) WITH
    (
        NoteID nvarchar(100)
    ) j2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS DayNumber, NoteID
    FROM OPENJSON(j1.NotesDay4) WITH
    (
        NoteID nvarchar(100)
    ) j2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS DayNumber, NoteID
    FROM OPENJSON(j1.NotesDay5) WITH
    (
        NoteID nvarchar(100)
    ) j2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 AS DayNumber, NoteID
    FROM OPENJSON(j1.NotesDay6) WITH
    (
        NoteID nvarchar(100)
    ) j2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 AS DayNumber, NoteID
    FROM OPENJSON(j1.NotesDay7) WITH
    (
        NoteID nvarchar(100)
    ) j2
) j2;
```

Comment: That's done it!!! Thank you. I think that's probably a much easier and obvious solution for most people on here, including yourself. But like I said, this isn't my regular job! Thank you so very much @Charlieface

Answer (score 0):

..if the json structure is slightly different and if there can be only one object in the userdetails and notesdayX arrays …[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5e6a3a2f8f97664acbd9ee3a823dd2cd):

```
declare @j nvarchar(max) =N'
[
{"UserDetails":[
{"UserID":"User1",
"NotesDay1":[{"NoteID":"12345"}],
"NotesDay2":[],
"NotesDay3":[],
"NotesDay4":[{"NoteID":"23456"}],
"NotesDay5":[],
"NotesDay6":[{"NoteID":"34567"}],
"NotesDay7":[{"NoteID":"45678"}]
}
]},
{"UserDetails":[
{"UserID":"User2",
"NotesDay1":[{"NoteID":"54321"}],
"NotesDay2":[{"NoteID":"65432"}],
"NotesDay3":[],
"NotesDay4":[{"NoteID":"76543"}],
"NotesDay5":[],
"NotesDay6":[],
"NotesDay7":[{"NoteID":"87654"}]
}
]}
]';

select *
from openjson(@j)
with
(
userid nvarchar(100) '$.UserDetails[0].UserID',
notesday1 nvarchar(10) '$.UserDetails[0].NotesDay1[0].NoteID',
notesday4 nvarchar(10) '$.UserDetails[0].NotesDay4[0].NoteID',
notesday7 nvarchar(10) '$.UserDetails[0].NotesDay7[0].NoteID'
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, won't this just return only the first row of my JSON data?

Comment: @Dan..if the array consists of userdetails : `[{detail1:[]}, {detail2:[]}]` ..then openjson() will return two rows, one for each detail. the sample @json in the question, has the second userdetail nested in the first one..and for that @json even the query of the question will not work.

Comment: I tested the query you suggested, and it did indeed just return the one row. The original query doesn't work above when combined with more than 2 of the different days, but for the first two it did. This is why I'm stuck lol.